# ¿Porque mi SQL consume mucha memoria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen dia tengo un problema con mi SQL server, lo que pasa es que cuando abro un archivo donde tengo transacciones mi SQL empieza a consumir demasiada memoria empieza con 53 MB y esta cantidad empieza subir hasta el grado de llegar a trabar mi SQL y esto pasa aunque no realice ninguna transacción y solamente pasa con un archivo en especifico, con los demás no me da  ese problema, no se que pueda estar causando esto espero me puedan ayudar. Dejo una imagen de los niveles que alcanza:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sql server consume todo lo que le des, es recomendable siempre limitar el uso de la memoria para que este no crashee

Management Studio: Conecta el Management Studio al servidor indicado - en el Explorador de objetos seleccione el Servidor y desde su menú contextual (botón izquierdo del ratón) seleccione "Propiedades" - Seleccione "Memoria" en el panel izquierdo y modifique los valores de "Cantidad mínima (y máxima) de memoria del servidor"

Comment: Que tal y cuanto es recomendable asignarle soy muy nuevo usando sql y desconozco a cuanto debo limitarlo

Comment: Si es tu maquina de desarrollo, limitarlo al 50% de tu memoria, si es el servidor de sql dedicado para ello el 75% a 85%, eso mi recomendacion personal

Comment: El panel que muestras no tiene nada que ver con la gestión de memoria de SQL Server. Es un tema bastante complejo, pero la configuración de tú servidor le dice al SQL que tiene una memoria "ilimitada", por tanto cuando lo necesita el gestor de memoria, le dice al de tu SO, que necesita x cantidad, y este le da lo que tiene. A partir de ahí, si el gestor de memoria de tú SO, mientras no le pida al de SQL recuperarla memoria, este no la devuelve, y la  reserva para futuras querys.Lo que deberías de revisar además de ponerle límites, es tú ARCHIVO de transacciones.

Comment: Un buen artículo en inglés sobre la memoria del sql lo puedes obtener de la web de Brent Ozar [Guía MsSql Memory](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/)

Comment: Creo que el problema radica cuando en ese sql ejecute esta sentencia SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT si ejecuto esa sentencia me empieza a consumir memoria y si cierro el arcivo y lo vuelvo a abrir aunque ya no ejecute esa sentencia me empieza a consumir memoria.

Comment: Porque antes de que ejecutara esa sentencia ya tenia mas transacciones y no había tenido problema, el problema llego hasta que ejecute esa sentencia

Comment: Lo que muestras que consume memoria no es tu "SQL Server", sino el "SQL Server Management Studio", abreviado como SSMS, que es el programa que utilizas para conectarte a SQL Server, que es el motor de base de datos y que seguramente está consumiendo otra cantidad importante de memoria.  El difícil decir por qué razón el Management Studio está consumiendo esta cantidad sin ver lo que le estás dando, pero de manera general supongo que tiene que traer una gran cantidad de datos del servidor (que puede estar en tu mismo equipo) al cliente (que es el SSMS).

Comment: Puede ser que el SSMS esté almacenando la información en memoria para mostrarla en un grid. Generalmente no hace falta traer tantos datos, pero si no tienes de otra, puedes cambiar el modo de salida a _texto_, con lo que el consumo probablemente bajará significativamente. Dado que es un _script_ específico el que provoca el problema, analiza este scirpt pensando como programador... si tu tuvieras que hacer un programa que lo procese, ¿qué de este haría que consuma tanta memoria?